# Frozen cursor after login

Tags: windows-10

I have some Windows 10 Home. On login screen where I choose username and type password cursor works perfectly, after login for couple of seconds cursor works and suddenly freezing. I suspect that one of applications working in background locks cursor somehow. How I can figure out why and by what cursor is blocked?
Tried to uinstall McAfee antivirus but I failed without mouse (one of buttons can't be checked with `Tab` key).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure out why it happen, but I managed to resolve problem. I used the laptop so long as battery goes to 0%. After charging it to full, switching on every works fine.